# Distorted wallpaper upon login after updating to 15.04

Tags: drivers, 15.04, intel-graphics, desktop-background

After I upgraded from 14.10 to 15.04 now whenever I log in, My wallpaper becomes distorted and a series of black and white hyphen-like bars appear vertically on the right edge of the screen.

[This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221403) is talking about the same issue but does not provide any solution.

[This is also](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2266382) a discussion to the related problem but I couldn't find my solution.

Is it a display driver issue or a configuration issue? how can I fix it?

Regards,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A clean install will solve your issue. From the solved thread below it seems it was a driver issue.

Try a clean install and if it doesn't work, let me know. I have a few other suggestions. Good luck!

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2266382

Comment: I can't do a clean install at the moment. Can you put forward your other suggestions